# Category ID Shows 0 for Query Definition Retrieve

Tags: ssjs, query-definition

I am trying to Retrieve the Query Definition's Folder ID using SSJS but every time it shows 0 for CategoryID for the Query Definition.

My simple SSJS as follows:

```
 <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1");

var results=QueryDefinition.Retrieve({Property:"CategoryID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"19543"});

    Write("Query Name         : " +results[0].Name+"\n");
    Write("Query ExternalKey  : " +results[0].CustomerKey+"\n");
    Write("Query Folder ID    : " +results[0].CategoryID+"\n");


</script>




When i run this script i get all values such as Name, CustomerKey but CategoryID Keep showing 0. I tried different folder & trying to retrieve all queries but still CategoryID shows '0'..
```

Any one can help please..?

Are we able to retrieve CategoryID for QueryDefinition..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why core function is not working to get CategoryID but I checked it and it didn't work for me too.

You may retrieve it with Platform functions:

```
<script runat="server"> 



Platform.Load("core", "1");

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "QueryDefinition");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CustomerKey");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CategoryID");

var sfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "Property", "CustomerKey");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp, "Value", "da966445-328f-4eec-8189-c25e81320143");

Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", sfp);

var StatusAndRequestID = [0,0];
var Result = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr,StatusAndRequestID);

if(Result != null) {

     Write(Result[0].CategoryID);

}

else { Write("Query couldn't be found");}
</script>
```